# Disk caching in Apache2 reverse proxying configuration

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, proxypass, mod-cache

I'm trying to setup a reverse disk-caching proxy on my apache2 instance, to avoid hitting a publicly available resource too often.  The setup is like this:

```
local-node --(http)--> reverse-proxy --(https)--> original-resource
```

To achieve this, I did the following setup on `reverse-proxy`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  CacheRoot /path/with/www-data/read-write-permissions
  CacheDefaultExpire 86400
  SSLProxyEngine On

  <Location "/location/">
    ProxyPass https://example.com/location/
    ProxyPassReverse https://example.com/location/
    CacheEnable disk
  </Location>
```

I then enabled modules `cache`, `cache_disk`, `ssl`, `proxy`, `proxy_html`, `proxy_http`.

The apache2 service was properly reloaded and accessing `http://reverse-proxy/location/file` works on `local-node`.  I see logs on the apache2 server indicating a file from the proxied location being served.

What I do not see is the disk cache being formed.  If I list `/path/with/www-data/read-write-permissions`, then the directory is empty.  <strike>I'm now worried that the caching is not working as expected</strike> I can confirm that this is **not working** and I continue to hit `https://example.com/location/` at every request of `local-node` to the original `file` - which I definitely would like to avoid.

Question(s):

1. How to fix this to enable proper disk caching?
2. How to ensure that the remote resource is not being hit all the time?